# Passing props to UseEffect hook from Parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, axios, react-hooks

I'm trying to pass props from my Parent component to child component. Here are the important snippets:

Snippet 1: This is the object that contains the prop (integer).

```
 const cardProps = {
        cardProps0: 0,
```

Snippet 2: This is the Card component within the parent component that carries the prop to child component

```
return (
<MyCardLink source={cardProps.cardProps0} />
```

Snippet 3: This is the child component (MyCardLink)

```
useEffect((props) => {
        axios
            .get(
                'http://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=economy&apiKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
            )
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
                setNews(res.data.articles[props.source]);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }, []);
```

The goal is that [prop.source] contains a number value from a list of an array served by an API. If I just place a number value in the child component (MyCardLink) in place of [props.source] on the setNews function then it renders the component no problem.

My problem is when I pass the prop from parent component to child component and use [prop.source], nothing renders and all I get from the console log is:

> Cannot read property 'source' of undefined.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of passing `props` into your `useEffect`, you need to add into your `MyCardLink` component's parameters as:

```
const MyCardLink = (props) => {
    // your component's defintion
}
```

Additionally you can destructure as the following:

```
const MyCardLink = (props) => {
   const { source } = props

   // ... rest
}
```

Then simply you can use in your `useEffect` without `props` as:

```
useEffect(() => {
   axios.get(
          'http://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=economy&apiKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
       )
       .then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
            setNews(res.data.articles[source]);
       })
       .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
       }
   );
}, []);
```

---

Based on your other question from the comment section what I would do is:

1. Change the initial value of the state from `""` to `null` as `const [news, setNews] = useState(null)`.
2. Also I would use `&&` for `null` check and render `<Card />` component only if it has value as `news && <Card className={classes.root}>` in your `return`.

The reason behind this is your **API** response is arriving **asynchronously**.

Comment: Yep, tried that way too. I get cannot read property "url" of undefined. Here is a link to the [component codebase](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-gauss-gwoij?file=/src/App.js). I'm sure there's something going on under the hood that I don't know about.

Comment: @Pacholoamit It seems you shared an empty codebase, what I see there is a basic **Hello CodeSandbox** text.

Comment: Ooops, sorry I forgot to save hehe. Please check the app.js component now.

Comment: @Pacholoamit Just extended my answer to resolve your other issue.

Comment: Alright, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I get what you are saying, I'll probably add a ternary statement? Sorry, I'm new to this so I'm not really good with the syntax, I've been learning react for a month but I'll research more on the null check and render if news. if you would like to explain further in syntax, I'd much appreciate it but if not then thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction :)

Comment: @Pacholoamit Yes, I guess [Ternary Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) also works for this case. Keep up the good work, learning new stuff is always interesting!

Comment: Hello, one more thing. I wrote `news &&` after the `return (` method but all I get is `
Error: MyCardLink(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.` I really don't get it because it shows the API request in the console.log.

Comment: @Pacholoamit Then you can use **Ternary** instead as `return news ? <Card /> : null`.

Comment: OMYGOD! IT FRIGGIN WORKED HAHAHAHA. Bro... It;s been 7 hours and it's 3:00 AM here. I knew it had to be a ternary but i thought it was a dumb idea. I never knew you could do `return news ? ( ALL COMPONENTS) : null`. Bro, I owe you big time

Comment: @Pacholoamit Happy to help! :D

Comment: @norbitrial don't you have to put the `source` variable in the dependency array of the useEffect? everytime i use an arbitrary variable inside a useEffect, i always get a warning that useEffect cannot see it

Answer (score 1):

use use props in component below:

```
const MyCardLink =(props)=>{
 ...
 ...
 ...
}
export default MyCardLink;
```

Comment: Yep, tried that way too. I get cannot read property "url" of undefined. Here is a link to the [component codebase](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-gauss-gwoij?file=/src/App.js). I'm sure there's something going on under the hood that I don't know about.

Comment: thanks.I do not understand what you mean? Please help more

Comment: I did const MyCardLink =(props) =>.... but I get an error say "Cannot read property 'url' of undefined." That link is the codebase of my entire component so you can have a look of the entire picture

Comment: how see entre picture.where is it